# How to find Firebase UI Dependency for Android Studio 2020.3.1

Tags: java, android, firebaseui

I'm getting errors while I try to run my program. An error like this.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtlLj.png) You can see in below image.(It's showing that "Could not find Could not find com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestor:8.0.1.")

Please tell me what is current virsion of Firebaseui dependency virsion.

And also tell me how can I find others dependency virsion in future.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to know what is the current version of the FirebaseUI dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Well I dont see 8.0.1 on the official Firebase website either, that is why your build is failing:

Information/Documentation: https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/firebaseui-android/

Releases page is: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/releases

**To Install Version 8.0:**

```
dependencies {
    // FirebaseUI for Firebase Realtime Database
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:8.0.0'

    // FirebaseUI for Cloud Firestore
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:8.0.0'

    // FirebaseUI for Firebase Auth
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:8.0.0'

    // FirebaseUI for Cloud Storage
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:8.0.0'
}
```

**Dependencies:**

> Compatibility with Firebase / Google Play Services libraries
>
> FirebaseUI libraries have the following transitive dependencies on the

```
Firebase SDK:

firebase-ui-auth
|--- com.google.firebase:firebase-auth
|--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth

firebase-ui-database
|--- com.google.firebase:firebase-database

firebase-ui-firestore
|--- com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore

firebase-ui-storage
|--- com.google.firebase:firebase-storage
```

> You can see the specific dependencies associated with each release on
> the Releases page.

https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-android#dependencies